# How to catch errors and send responses in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my bot to send a message to the chat when someone types a non-existent command. I tried this but nothing happened. Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as: " + bot.user.name + "\n")

@bot.command()
async def asdasd(ctx):
    try:
        if asdasd:
            await ctx.send('asd')
    except discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound:
        await ctx.send('error')

bot.run('My Token Here')
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an exception handler event specifically for this!

## Example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("That command wasn't found! Sorry :(")
```

Read up more about it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.on_command_error). All the different errors can be found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20errors#exceptions).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You are the best.